# Reformat CSV file using Python and Pandas, (AWK)?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, awk

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Names, Size, State, time1,   time2,       
S1,    22,   MD  , 0.022, ,  523.324
S2,    22,   MD  , 4.32,  , 342.54 
S3,    22,   MD  , 3.54,  ,   0.32
S4,    22,   MD  , 4.32,  ,  0.54  
S1,    33,   MD  , 5.32,  ,  0.43
S2,    33,   MD  , 11.54, ,  0.65
S3,    33,   MD  , 22.5,  ,  0.324
S4,    33,   MD  , 45.89  ,  0.32
S1,    44,  MD  , 3.53   ,  3.32
S2,    44,  MD  ,  4.5   ,  0.322
S3,    44,  MD  , 43.65  ,   45.78
S4,    44,   MD,   43.54 , 0.321
```

I do not care about the **state** column

I need for my output file to look like this:

```
 Size ,   S1` ,    S2  ,   S3  ,   S4   

  22   ,  0.022 ,  4.32 ,  45.89 ,  4.32

  33  ,  5.32,    11.54 ,  22.5,   45.89, 

  44  ,  3.53,    4.5,     43.65,  43.54

        3 values, 3 values, 3,values, 3 values
```

As you can see the output file includes different headers that are the values from the first csv file.  The csv file is ordered by the **Size** column. In other words I want to know which time is associated with the size for each file **(S1,S2,S3,S4)** . The order of the columns are changed also. The size column in now the first column in the output file. Also the last row indicates the total number of values in each column.

My code thus far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\file.csv',usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(['Names','FileSize','x','y','z'],df.columns)) *#add column headers... (this did not do it correctly)*
df_out=df.groupby('Names','FileSize').count().reset_index() *#suppose to print distinct values*
df_out.to_csv('processed_data_out.csv', columns['Names','FileSize','x','y','z'], header=False,index=False)
```

I know I didn't use the last column `time2` because I did not know how to add it so that the user can know what times (both time1 and time2) are associated  with the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is not necessary here, since you are already using python, I would stay with python:

*convert.py:*

```
import csv 
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = {}
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in reader:
        size = int(row[1])
        time1 = float(row[3])

        if not size in data:
            data[size] = []

        data[size].append(time1)


writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(["Size","S1","S2","S3","S4"])
for item in data:
    row = [item]
    row.extend(data[item])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Call it like this:

```
python convert.py C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\file.csv
```

Output:

```
Size,S1,S2,S3,S4
33,5.32,11.54,22.5,45.89
44,3.53,4.5,43.65,43.54
22,0.022,4.32,3.54,4.32
```

---

Btw, an `awk` solution could look like this:

```
awk -F'[, ]*' '
    NR>1{
        a[$2]=a[$2]","$4
    }
    END{
        for(i in a){
            print i""a[i]
        }
    }' input.csv
```

Comment: this only prints the size column without any duplicates

Comment: Cannot reproduce that. Your input file is called `input.csv` (or you changed that)?

Comment: I've changed the code, now you can pass the filename via commandline.

Comment: filename= sys.argv[1] gives me an out of range error

Comment: you need to pass the filename!

Comment: Yeah.. realized that after the fact.. Im new to Python. I got it to work. THANKS!

Comment: Btw, quick and dirty with `awk`: `awk -F'[, ]*' 'NR>1{a[$2]=a[$2]","$4}END{for(i in a){print i""a[i]}}' input.csv` ;)

Comment: how would I format this to print to a separate csv. if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: You need to add `> output.csv`.

Comment: where on the last line

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue

```
awk -F, -f table.awk
```

where

```
$ cat table.awk

    NR == 1 {
            h = $1           # save header
            next
    }

    NR == 2 {
            p = $2           # to match blocks
            v = $2           # value accumulator
    }

    p == $2 {                # we're in the same block
            v = v FS $4      # start accumulate values
            if (h != "") {   # if we're not done with header
                    h = h FS $1    # accumulate header values
            }
    }

    p != $2 {                # we're in a new block
            if (h != "") {   # if not printed yet, print header
                    print h
                    h = ""   # and reset
            }
            print v          # print values
            p = $2           # set new block indicator
            v = $2 FS $4     # accumulate values
    }

    END {
            print v          # for the final block print values
    }
```

test

```
awk -F, -f table.awk << !
> Names, Size, State, time1,   time2,
> S1,    22,   MD  , 0.022, ,  523.324
> S2,    22,   MD  , 4.32,  , 342.54
> S3,    22,   MD  , 3.54,  ,   0.32
> S4,    22,   MD  , 4.32,  ,  0.54
> S1,    33,   MD  , 5.32,  ,  0.43
> S2,    33,   MD  , 11.54, ,  0.65
> S3,    33,   MD  , 22.5,  ,  0.324
> S4,    33,   MD  , 45.89  ,  0.32
> S1,    44,  MD  , 3.53   ,  3.32
> S2,    44,  MD  ,  4.5   ,  0.322
> S3,    44,  MD  , 43.65  ,   45.78
> S4,    44,   MD,   43.54 , 0.321
> !
Names,S1,S2,S3,S4
22, 0.022, 4.32, 3.54, 4.32
33, 5.32, 11.54, 22.5, 45.89
44, 3.53   ,  4.5   , 43.65  ,   43.54
```

Comment: this prints the state column

Comment: don't think so.  just added a test output based on your input data.  Note that there is no reference to third field in the code to be printed.  Perhaps your sample input and your test input are different?

Comment: @karakfa What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042568/reformat-csv-file-using-python-and-pandas-awk/32058235?noredirect=1#comment52018403_32058235)?

Comment: @hek2mgl much shorter but I think loses the order.  May be OK for the use though with a sort.

Comment: @karakfa You are right. `gawk` offers [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea behind both awk solutions, but for people who want an intermediate style of awk that is not so terse and looks more like other scripting solutions, consider this:

```
BEGIN { 
  while ("cat data1" | getline) {
    if ($0 ~ /S[1-4]/) {
      split($0,temp,/[ ,]+/)
      oline[temp[2]] = oline[temp[2]] " ,  " temp[4]
    }
  }
  print "Size ,   S1 ,    S2  ,   S3  ,   S4"
  for (i in oline) print i oline[i]
}



OUTPUT:
Size ,   S1 ,    S2  ,   S3  ,   S4
22 ,  0.022 ,  4.32 ,  3.54 ,  4.32
33 ,  5.32 ,  11.54 ,  22.5 ,  45.89
44 ,  3.53 ,  4.5 ,  43.65 ,  43.54
```

If the data are not in such a nice row order, "sort -nk2 -k1" could be used instead of "cat" to make sure that it is robust to row reordering.  The S1-S4 row naming is still assumed.